Exterior drywall. Cover or remove
I want to do a home upgrade, new siding , windows and roof. My home currently has exterior drywall under vinyl siding, no wrap.  Once I remove siding drywall I will have hundreds of holes. Was thinking of re-sheathing entire house with OSB over the drywall. Then wrap and reside. Other option would be to remove all drywall which would be a pain as the house is two story.
Any advice, suggestions is greatly appreciate

Unless the drywall is damaged(much more than nail/screw holes), then most places charge money to get rid of it.  I like saving money.

Never heard of exterior drywall before.  Is it paper-faced like regular drywall?

@Huesmann   Was new to me also last year(question I read).  Seems to be special 'drywall' for outside surfaces

Its exterior grade, the paper facing is supposedly weather resistant. I cut out and installed a new window a few years back. The board was in fair shape (dry, no mold). I do know that nails that do not or have not hit a stud simply fall out. Horrible stuff

OSB is a reasonable choice for added sturdiness. What kind of climate zone are you in? (Wet/dry? Hot/cold? I’m thinking about insulation, among other things.)

Polyiso sheathing board is normally a good idea if your home isn't starting from "already superinsulated"

Southeast Virginia, Semi mild  climate.

It’s hard to quantify, but you might look at the cost/benefit of exterior insulation panels.
